# How to test if a @property from ObjC object is nil in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a model object written in Objective-C, which has a property of the type `NSMutableArray`.

It can either be `nil` or has a valid object reference.

I am using bridging header and I have a few files written in Swift.

In the Swift file I want to iterate through the objects in the array, only if it has something in it.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried things such as:

```
   if let a = MyObj.myArray {
   }
   if(MyObj.myArray != nil) {
   }
   if(MyObj.myArray != NSNull()) {
   }
```

I finally got the hang of optionals in Swift code alone, but I am not able to understand the behavior when I am passing around objects written in Objective-C in Swift code.

My Actual Code Looks like this :
Code :

```
if let values = attribute.values {
    for val in values {
        print(val);
    }
    return true;
}

Exception:

-[NSNull countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: what went wrong? `if let` is the appropriate choice

Comment: "I finally got the hang of optionals in Swift" Evidently not. Also, be careful with the phrase "only if it has something in it"; a nil NSMutableArray is not the same as an empty NSMutableArray.

Comment: "if let" did not work. It went inside the if clause and I got an unrecognised selector sent to [NSNull count] error.

Comment: Is `MyObj` and instance of your class? If so, it should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I have added my actual code snippet in the question.

Comment: `attribute.values` is a `NSNull` instance rather than an array.

Comment: Yes. I figured that out from the exception, but I'm unable to figure out why it became a NSNull instance. The objC code earlier was checking only for "nil".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells us the problem:

> -[NSNull countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Your `attribute.values` isn't nil or an `NSMutableArray`. It's `[NSNull null]`.

`NSNull` is a real object that's used instead of nil in collections, because the common Foundation collections (`NSArray` and `NSDictionary`) cannot store nil as a value.

We most often come across `NSNull` when decoding a data structure from JSON. When the JSON decoder finds `null` (a JSON literal) in an array or object, it stores `[NSNull null]` in the corresponding `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Something like this should work:

```
if let values = attribute.values where values != NSNull() {
    for val in values {
        print(val);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Great! That helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the new Nullability annotation syntax for your Objective-C properties. These annotations help communicate to Swift whether you intend for an object to be nil or not. For example:

```
@property (nullable) NSMutableArray* myArray;
```

With these annotations, your Objective-C objects should work just like a native Swift object. You can do an if let or any other nil check.

```
if let arr = myObject.myArray {
    // Do something with arr
}
else {
    // Object is nil do something else
}

if myObject.myArray == nil {
    // Array is nil, handle it.
}
```

You can read more about Nullability annotations for Objective-C at the Apple Swift blog.

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: Adding the nullable property didn't work either. I have updated the question with my actual code snippet.